# Remove "Heard you say..." using Speech Recognition API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

Currently using the **Windows Phone 8 Speech Recognition API**. I've managed to get the basics but there is one problem. Whenever I click the Speech Button which I've added, I say the whatever I want and then it says "Heard you say.." and says what I say.

Is there a way to only show the Listening menu and then once I've said what I want to say it does whatever? I just want to remove the "Heard you say..." menu.

So far this is what I've got:

```
SpeechRecognizerUI speechRecognition = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await speechRecognition.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

if (recoResult.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
{
   textblock1.text = recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the feature by using this property: `SpeechRecognizerUISetting.ReadOutEnabled` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.recognition.speechrecognizeruisettings.readoutenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

```
speechRecognition.Settings.ReadoutEnabled = false;
```